# Changing python syntax coloring in eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, syntax-highlighting

I am using Eclipse Indigo for python coding.

When I comment something, I want the color of the comment to be blue

how can I achieve?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you use the PyDev plug-in you can access the color settings in the Window/Preferences/PyDev/Editor menu.